# mod_rewrite Remove .php not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

The first rule is working so it's correctly redirecting the browser. However, the second rule which should be stripping .php so that visitors can go to domain.com/services instead of domain.com/services.php is not working. The third condition which adds a / to the end, works.

Any idea why stripping .php gives me a 404 error:

```
The requested URL /s/p/domain.com/public/packing-tips.php was not found on this server?
```

Any advice?

Comment: If you directly go the URL (with .php in the end), does it show you the webpage? For example, if you go to domain.com/services.php or domain.com/packing-tips.php then do you get a 404?

Comment: No, I do not get a 404, the page displays exactly as it should. However, when I remove the .php manually from the address bar, it displays the error above.

Answer (score 0):

try this dear:

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$1
```

hope will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try removing this line and check again:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
```

Answer (score 0):

For stripping out .php extension use this .htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: When I go to domain.com/sizes-and-pricing.php it displays correctly. When I remove .php this error appears:

The requested URL /sizes-and-pricing/.php was not found on this server.

Comment: @samseaborn: Slightly modified my answer to take care of trailing slash `/` issue as encountered by you. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
# force canonical name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA]

# Add .php to requested resource (if such php file does exist)
# e.g. www.example.com/services/ => www.example.com/services.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1.php [QSA,L]

# Force trailing slash to be present (only if such file does not exist)
# e.g. www.example.com/services => www.example.com/services/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,QSA]
```

If you request this URL `domain.com/services` it will be redirected to `domain.com/services/` if such file/folder does not exist. Then, if  (ONLY IF) `domain.com/services.php` is does exist, it will be rewritten to `domain.com/services.php`. If there is no such php file, then you should see 404 error.

In theory you could add these lines after "force canonical name" rule, then you can get rid of few RewriteCond rules later (useful if you have quite a bit rewrite rules), but you have to verify this on your site -- it works fine for me, but you may have specific circumstances:

```
# Do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]
```